# Remote login option not saving after reboot

Tags: ssh, login, remote-control

I have two Mac minis which both lose the remote login option after a reboot, and I don't know why. After I check that box, it saves, at least during that session. But after a reboot, I always find the box unchecked:

[image]

macOS versions:

- macOS 10.12.3
- OS X 10.10.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround that can force Remote Login to be turned on, when the computer is powered up. This can be a good choice for someone who is working in a workgroup with several machines.

I have installed LaunchControl, and went in Global Daemons, then created a new plist named as com.remotelogin.true (you can choose the name you want) there with:

[image]

**NOTE:**

After you choose Save and Load, it will give you an error, but if you go to terminal with,

```
sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin
```

you will see that remote login is now on.